# Alt, Meta and other modifier keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, xorg, key-binding

I want to get more combos in Emacs, so I tried to bind Alt, Super, Hyper via modmap to keys. I failed at it. So I tried to use `xdotool`.

I started `emacs -Q` for clean experiment. Pressed <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and executed in other terminal:

```
xdotool key  --window 119537875 "meta+x"
xdotool key  --window 119537875 "alt+x"
```

Both commands resulted in `M-x runs the command execute-extended-command`. So, Emacs do not differ between Alt and Meta. How can I fix it?

Comment: How do *you* distinguish from Alt and Meta, what physical keys would they be? Also I think you mean `C-h c` as `C-h C-c` is `describe-copying` here. (What's Hyper? too.)

Comment: This fancy modifiers bound to keys I bind them to via modmap. `C-h c` is `describe-key-briefly`. EDIT: Sorry for mistype of this binding. Thanks for correction.

Comment: Could someone explain to me how to bind ANY key to the meta key in emacs through the terminal? I am running OS X 10.8.3. Preferably I would like to bind [left-shift] to the meta-key